# prediction error variance

Tags: calculus, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be  random  variables  with  $\mu_{X}=\mathbb{E} X, \mu_{Y}=\mathbb{E} Y$, $\sigma_{X}^{2}=\operatorname{Var} X, \sigma_{Y}^{2}=\operatorname{Var} Y$ and $\rho_{X Y}=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Y}} \neq 0$.

Show that the best linear predictor of $Y$ given $X$ in the sense of minimizing the prediction error variance $\mathbb{E}(\hat{Y}-Y)^{2}$ is given by

$$\begin{aligned} a &=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_{x}^{2}} \\ b &=\mu_{Y}-\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_{X}^{2}} \mu_{X} \end{aligned}$$

How I proceeded:

- I want to find the derivative of $\mathbb{E}(\hat{Y}-Y)^{2}$ with respect to $a$ and $b$.
- The linear predictor of $Y$ given $X$ is given by $Y = a X + b$, so I can substitute this into $\mathbb{E}(\hat{Y}-Y)^{2}$, and find the deriative with respect to $a$ and $b$.

But I didn't get the right answer, so I think my method is wrong. I hope you guys will give me a hint or some links that can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking here: http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/eps_120/Toolkits/Toolkit_10.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Joe....